# long date format to short date in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

Trying to set Shortdate list into a Datagrid.ItemsSource

```
var query = from loan in Loans  
            select new {Date = loan.StatusCommittedDate}  
DataGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

it displays Date in "3/25/2011 12:00:00 AM" Format in the DataGrid
I only need the date, not the time so my Current Linq is

```
var query = from loan in Loans  
            select new {Date = loan.StatusCommittedDate.ToString()}  
DataGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList()
```

which displays in "2011-03-25" format which is what I want. So the Linq query works, but   inputting it into the datagrid is wrong and if I can get some guidances please. When I try   to display the information through a Datagrid in WPF I get this error

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method `System.String ToString()` method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Have you tried googling the exception? This happens anytime you try to invoke a method from SQL that doesn't translate to a method SQL knows about.

Answer (score 0):

Try performing the LINQ statement without the `ToString()` in it, saving the results to an intermediate variable.

Then manipulate the results before assigning to the grid. See if this works:

```
var dates = (from loan in Loans
             select loan.StatusCommittedDate).ToList();

DataGrid.ItemsSource = query.Select(d => d.ToString()).ToList();
```

I'm guessing you're displaying more than this in your grid, but it's all I can guess from the code you've included.

Comment: Tried and I get this error: Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you do NOT turn your perfectly good DateTime into a string just to format it.

Instead, leverage the ability to format at the latest possible moment inside WPF by configuring the DataGrid appropriately.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Status Committed Date"  
            Binding="{Binding Date, StringFormat=yyyy-mm-dd}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The important things to note:

- The bindings on specified columns have a context of a single instance of whatever list of objects you've provided. So in this case we bind to your `Date` property.
- There is a property on a Binding called StringFormat which will do exactly what you want. Its the same as whatever format you may have placed inside your ToString() call.

*Please note, I did not actually get a chance to jam the above XAML into a project to verify that it works, so there might be typos.*

Comment: Hi, I tried this method but I'm using telerik datagrid and it displays the information Blank, so the entire Datagrid is "populated" but with blank entries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023836/telerik-radgridview-wont-display-dates

Comment: I see from that question that you managed to get everything sorted in the end. Excellent.