# Telerik RadGridView won't display Dates

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, telerik

I'm trying to display my Date in a RadGridView in ShortDate Format.

The code I used to generate the column is this :

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="GenInq" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" 
  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,-14,0,14" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>  
        <telerik:GridViewColumn Header="Date" 
          Binding.XmlNamespaceManager="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}"/>
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>   
</telerik:RadGridView>`
```

This is my query i used to populate the DataGrid:

```
var query = from loan in Loans  
            select new {Date = loan.StatusCommittedDate}  

DataGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

The issue I'm having is that the Date Entries are appearing BLANK in the datagrid, it populates the grid with blank entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate the issue and got the same results you did.

You need to change the column definition accordingly:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Date"
    DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}"/>
```